# Positivstellensatz for non-polynomial term

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra, real-algebra

Can we use Positivstellensatz (P-satz) below for a **non-polynomial** term?

P-satz:
Let $R$ be real closed field. Let $f,g,h$ be finite families of **polynomials** in $R[X_{1} ,...,X_{n}]$. Denote by P the cone generated by $f$, $M$ the multiplicative monoid generated by $g$ and $I$ the ideal generated by $h$. Then the following properties are equivalent:

(i) The set $\{x\in R^n| f\geq 0, g\neq 0 , h=0\}$ is empty
(ii) There exist $f \in P, g\in M, h\in I$ such that $f+g^2 +h=0$.

Reference:
Bochnak et al. 1999

Comment: For which Ring you would like to apply it?

Comment: If you do not want to apply it to polynomials, then what else do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to say.

Comment: In my case, $f$ and $g$ have some non-linear term, e.g. $f(x)=\sin x (x^2+x^3)$. So there are some non-linear terms in the function (not only polynomials).  (Now, I am working on some robotics system that represented in some non-linear terms and some polynomial terms. I am just wondering: Whether can I apply the P-satz to my system or not to simplify the analysis. Thank you before)

Comment: So you want to replace the ring of polynomials with the ring of continuous functions? Or of all functions?

Comment: Exactly. Is it possible to apply positivstellensatz theorem for continuous (or all) functions? or the p-satz theorem above can only be applied for polynomials?

Comment: Actually I want to apply it to a smooth function, but continuous functions are also ok. Any idea?

Comment: In the case of univariate polynomials, there is such a Positivstellensatz for trigonometric polynomials, see http://www.math.washington.edu/~thomas/frg/frgbook/SIAMBookFinalvNov12-2012.pdf exercise 3.37. i would suppose that it can be generalized to more variables.